# Enable/Disable tasks in Crontab by Bash/Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

Is there a way to enable and disable Crontab tasks using Bash/Shell?

So when the user starts Server 1, it will enable the Server 1 Crontab line and so on.
And when the user stops Server 1, the Server 1 Crontab line get disabled (#).
Is this possible and how?

Thanks in advance

```
*/1 * * * * Server 1 check
*/1 * * * * Server 2 check
*/1 * * * * Server 3 check
```

Comment: You can use a sentinel directory to be used by all your scripts, and check in each script whether the sentinel they expect is here -- and if not, abort execution

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SERVERNUM=$1
```

To enable:

```
crontab -l | sed "/^#.*Server $SERVERNUM check/s/^#//" | crontab -
```

To disable:

```
crontab -l | sed "/^[^#].*Server $SERVERNUM check/s/^/#/" | crontab -
```

Transcript:

```
barmar@dev$ crontab -l
*/1 * * * * Server 1 check
*/1 * * * * Server 2 check
*/1 * * * * Server 3 check
barmar@dev$ crontab -l | sed '/^[^#].*Server 1 check/s/^/#/' | crontab -
barmar@dev$ crontab -l
#*/1 * * * * Server 1 check
*/1 * * * * Server 2 check
*/1 * * * * Server 3 check
barmar@dev$ crontab -l | sed '/^#.*Server 1 check/s/^#//' | crontab -
barmar@dev$ crontab -l
*/1 * * * * Server 1 check
*/1 * * * * Server 2 check
*/1 * * * * Server 3 check
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to add/remove a # in the crontab.
On = */1 * * * * Server 1 check
Off = #*/1 * * * * Server 1 check

Comment: Wonderfull, this works, the only problem I'm facing with is to make the Server number dynamic in Bash, the problem with that is, that #.*Server $1 check/ doesn't work, either "$1". So how do I pass variable $1 into the Numbers?

Comment: See modified commands. Note the change from single to double quotes, so that variables will be expanded.

Comment: Thanks that did the job, I still don't get why quotes are needed, and the redefining of $1.
Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: The quotes are needed because sed requires the command to be a single argument.

Comment: on my debian to comment works, but to uncomment for example with this command: `crontab -l | sed "/^#.*bin/script.sh/s/^#//"` it appears an error that says: "sed: -e expression  #1, char 25: command 's' not concluded"

Comment: @alexandre1985 You need to escape the `/` after `bin`, otherwise it ends the regular expression that's used to select the lines to process. So it thinks the `s` in `script` is the beginning of the substitution, `c` is the delimiter, and it complains that there's no matching delimiters.

Comment: `... | crontab` may be enough (no need of `-`). And, you could use `tee` to ensure current crontab state: `crontab -l | sed '...' | tee >(crontab)` or `crontab -l | sed '...' | tee /dev/stderr | crontab`

Comment: @F.Hauri Many versions of `crontab` don't allow it to be run without a filename argument -- typing `crontab` by itself followed by Ctl-d was a common error and wiped out your entire crontab. So you have to use `-` to make it clear that you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you add your cron jobs to `/etc/cron.d` for every server one script. Then let the cron script scan for some marker file if the cron job should be executed.

Comment: Another common arrangement is to have a directory `/path/to/servers` and then just a cron job with `run-parts /path/to/servers`. Then disabling a server anounts to renaming or removing its file in the `servers` directory. (`run-parts` is Debian-specific, but if your platform lacks it, it's not hard to roll your own.)

Answer (score 1):

As a quick and dirty fix, you can enable or disable the execute permission of the appropriate cron script.

E.g. if you like to prevent locate from automatically updating its database (which can be I/O consuming):

```
cd /etc/cron.daily

sudo chmod a-x locate
```

This may be against the cron framework, but it is quickly applied and it works in case of immediate needs.

Answer (score 0):

this is a variant, I use a cronjob that loads it self every night. I just edit a file and it gets reloaded at 10pm everynight. You could make the reload happen more often. I keep a directory of files for each of nodes. The trick is make sure that nobody comments out the reload line.

```
0 22 * * * crontab /home/ME/cron_files/NODE
```