# Remove @restart cronjob using bash

Tags: bash, sed, cron

I am trying to remove an @restart cronjob using bash and sed. The cronjob entry looks like this

```
@reboot /opt/nzbget/nzbget -D
```

I have tried using the help posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011065/enable-disable-tasks-in-crontab-by-bash-shell) but it uses regex and non-@reboot cronjobs so doesn't work

I did try adapting it but failed

```
crontab -l | sed "/\@reboot \/opt\/nzbget\/nzbget \-D/" | crontab -
```

I left info out for when it is for a specific user this works thanks to answer below

```
crontab -l -u username | sed '\~@reboot /opt/nzbget/nzbget -D~d' | crontab -u username -
```

Comment: Are there other `@reboot` jobs? (That sed command of yours has no actions. It it just a pattern. You need to tell sed to actually do something (like delete the line, etc.).)

Comment: There can be other `@reboot` jobs, what @anubhava suggested removes all @reboot jobs

Comment: That answer should only delete the line that matches that exact pattern. Are you sure you used it exactly? It worked here on some faked input. Do the other lines have the same contents in them?

Comment: The other cronjob that got deleted was this: `@reboot sleep 180 && cd $PATH_UBOOQUITY && nohup java -jar $PATH_UBOOQUITY/Ubooquity.jar -webadmin -headless -port 2202` EDIT: Turns out It was an issue with different crontabs and I need to use crontab -l -u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe to this `sed` to delete that line:

```
sed '\~@reboot /opt/nzbget/nzbget -D~d'
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that deletes all lines. Using this syntax exactly `crontab -l | sed '\~@reboot /opt/nzbget/nzbget -D~d' | crontab -`

Comment: Working well now after I sorted my crontab per user issue, thanks. Can't seem to mark as answer though

Comment: Why do you escape the starting delimiter?

Comment: @hek2mgl: That is due to use of alternate delimiter `~` for searching in `sed`

Comment: @hek2mgl `~` is valid in an address and sed picks that interpretation and gets confused without the escaping apparently. (I had to try it to see.)

Comment: Right, we could use `'/@reboot \/opt\/nzbget\/nzbget -D/d'` also but that would require escaping `/` 3 times in search pattern.